# Drupal 9 "Rules" module alternative

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I've been breaking my head over this for a week now. I have been researching and reading with no results.

I have a site made in Drupal 9, and I want to change certain states (workflow), send emails, display messages depending on changes (updates) in some content types. I want to do all of this automatically without the user having to do it manually.

In Drupal 7 this was very easy using the "Rules" module but this is practically useless in Drupal 9. What alternatives are there? I don't want to build a site using Drupal 7 as it is coming to the end of its life. But if I use Drupal 9 I will not be able to do what I want.

Can anyone give me some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same boat. Not tested, but I found this module that might be an alternative:

- Business Rules | Drupal.org : https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules